# filter '_index' same way as '_type' in search across multiple index query elastic search

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have two indexes **index1** and **index2** and both has two types **type1** and **type2** with same name in elastic search.(please assume that we have valid business reason behind it)

I would like to search **index1 - type1** and **index2 -type2**

**here is my query**

```
POST _search
{
 "query": {
    "indices": {
      "indices": ["index1","index2"],      
      "query": {
        "filtered":{  
         "query":{
       "multi_match": {
           "query": "test",
           "type": "cross_fields",
           "fields": ["_all"]         
       }

        },
         "filter":{  
            "or":{  
               "filters":[  
                  {  
                     "terms":{ 
                                "_index":["index1"], // how can i make this work?
                               "_type": ["type1"]
                     }                      
                  },
                  {  
                     "terms":{ 
                               "_index":["index2"], // how can i make this work?
                               "_type": ["type2"]
                     }                      
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
      },
      "no_match_query":"none"
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem you are facing. Your query working fine for me and I have same scenario multiple indices having same type.

Comment: Hi Roopendra, when i execute above query it returns result from index1->type2 and index2->type1 which i don't want. I want only index1->type1 and index2->type2. I believe that's because it is not filtering terms on "_index" field. hope that make sense. many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [indices](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-filter.html), [type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-type-filter.html) in a  [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) filter to filter on type and index
The query would look something on these lines :

```
POST  index1,index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "test",
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "fields": [
            "_all"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "indices": {
                "index": "index1",
                "filter": {
                  "type": {
                    "value": "type1"
                  }
                },
                "no_match_filter": "none"
              }
            },
            {
              "indices": {
                "index": "index2",
                "filter": {
                  "type": {
                    "value": "type2"
                  }
                },
                "no_match_filter": "none"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Passing the index names in the url  example :  index1,index2/_search is a good practice else you risk executing  query across all indices in the cluster.

Comment: many thanks. Just one more improvement inside indices filter i would use terms so i can have multiple types in it.              **"filter": {
           "terms" : { "_type" : ["type1","type3","type5"]}                                   
                }**